# Директивы условной компиляции. Почему не работает программа?

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Честно сказать пока не совсем врубился в тему условной компиляции. В книге у меня эта тема описана как маленькое приложение к книге. Поэтому мало что сказано про неё. Взял пример из книги и решил его не много переделать, но выдаёт ошибку.

Возникли вот такие вопросы:
Прочему выдает ошибку в строке `strcpy_s(who, "Том");` ?

И корректно ли вообще писать `COMPILED_BY == a` ? У меня в книге написано, что за #if должно следовать либо константное выражение, либо предварительно определённые идентификаторы. Как идентификатор может быть не определён заранее? Я это не совсем понимаю. Г. Шилдт имеет в виду что ли не писать так:

```
#if COMPILED_BY == int a = 5
```

Объясните пожалуйста что к чему. 
Заранее спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
#define JOHN 0
#define BOB 1
#define TOM 2
char who[80];
int a = 4;
#define COMPILED_BY TOM
#if COMPILED_BY == JOHN
strcpy_s(who, "Джон");
#elif COMPILED_BY == BOB
strcpy_s(who, "Боб");
#elif COMPILED_BY == TOM

strcpy_s(who, "Том");
#elif COMPILED_BY == a
who = "А";
#endif
int main() {

}
```

Comment: if condition not allowed in macros

Comment: use `#define COMPILED_BY_BOB` and `#ifdef COMPILED_BY_BOB`

Comment: *"Прочему выдает ошибку"* - ошибки следует приводить в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает потому что вне функций можно только объявлять разное и определять переменные, но не выполнять произвольные выражения. Перенесите вызовы `strcpy_s(who, "Боб");` внутрь `main`. A c `COMPILED_BY == a` проблема в том, что `a` является именем переменной, а не макросом или константным выражением (и `who = "А";` кстати тоже невалидно). Поэтому при подстановке в блок `COMPILED_BY == a` препроцессор заменит его на `2 == 0` (приняв пустое значение справа за 0). Однако данный пример все равно будет работать, так как до этого блока не дойдет.

```
#include <string.h>

#define JOHN 0
#define BOB 1
#define TOM 2

#define COMPILED_BY TOM

int main()
{
    char who[80];
    int a = 4;
#if COMPILED_BY == JOHN
    strcpy(who, "Джон");
#elif COMPILED_BY == BOB
    strcpy(who, "Боб");
#elif COMPILED_BY == TOM
    strcpy(who, "Том");
#elif COMPILED_BY == a
    who = "А";
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EExfssjgyYPNJPso)

Comment: Спасибо. А что на счёт:

Comment: Спасибо, а что на счёт:
У меня в книге написано, что за #if должно следовать либо константное выражение, либо предварительно определённые идентификаторы. Как идентификатор может быть не определён заранее? Я это не совсем понимаю. Г. Шилдт имеет в виду что ли не писать так:

#if COMPILED_BY == int a = 5

Comment: @JustLearn За `#if` всегда должно следовать константное выражение. А при использовании в этом константном выражении не определенных идентификаторов, они заменяются на 0. Вот в вашем примере не определен идентификатор `a`. Он будет принят за 0

Comment: Понял. 
Можете подсказать как на практике можно использовать директивы условной компиляции? А то в интернете ничего не найти...

Comment: @JustLearn А это тянет на отдельный вопрос...

Comment: пожалуй соглашусь )) Вы очень понятно объясняете что к чему. Я сейчас тему создам. Зайдёте? Называться будет: зачем нужны директивы условной компиляции, их практическое применение